# Obj C: Pass the name of an object from one class to another from method call

Tags: objective-c, object, methods

How do you pass the name of an object from one class method to use another class method?  Say if the class that calls the other classes method is called class2 and the other is class1.

class2 is not required to know anything about class1's object. So if inside a class2 method something like this was called:

```
int idNum = [class1 getidNum:@"blockKind1" coord:tileCoord];
```

class1's method would be able to interpret that object name somehow of one of its own. I know that isn't right, just an example.

Current "class2" interface as requested:

```
@interface HeroClass : CCLayer {
    DebugZoneLayer * debugZoneLayer;

    CCSprite *_heroSprite;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *_heroSpriteSheet;
    CCAction *_heroSpriteFlyAction;
    NSMutableArray *_collisPushPoints;

    @public int _collisPushPointsNums;

    @public float _travelRectCenterPointX;
    @public float _travelRectCenterPointY;

    NSMutableArray *_travelRectCenterPoints;

    @public float _travelRectSteps;

    /* amount of spacing in px between each center point
     of a rect that checks collision detection */

    @public int _rectCheckRes;

    @public int _speed;

    @public float _heroRectLookAhead;

    @public CGPoint _vel;

    @public CGRect _travelRectForTiles;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What's that "name of object"?

Comment: class1 has an object named blockKind1, but class2 just wants to return an int from class1 by doing a method call using that object name.

Comment: @user: By "object" do you mean "ivar"? `@interface class1 : NSObject { int blockKind1; } ... @end`

Comment: @user: Just show your current `@interface`.

Comment: @user: I can't see anything related to blockKind1 or tileCoord

Comment: That method call is in class2 calling a method in class1.  tileCoord is created and figured out in the class2 method that has a call to a method in class1.  My whole point is that blockKind1 would not have to be created in my interface. I simply want to pass on the name of it and have the called method in class1 to interpret the name and use it.  blockKind1 exists in class1, not class2.

Comment: `blockKind1` exists _in what form_ in `class1`? As an ivar or a method? If ivar, what type is the ivar? Or do you want to calculate some kind of value, based on the _string_ `@"blockKind1"`? What you're asking is very unclear. If you need to call a custom method on another object, just call the method and pass whatever arguments are appropriate.

Comment: @user586006: I think your question is confusing people because objects do not have "names." Variables and properties do, as do methods. Your phrasing is incredibly vague, so it's hard to tell what you mean to do.

Comment: Just trying the best I can here. I'm sorry that you weren't able to help me. Checking out what Terry posted to figure out if it's what I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. We're just trying to help you help us help you `:D` by asking questions that will clarify your meaning and terminology.

Comment: I think I was just using the entirely wrong vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Key Value Coding?](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)

> a mechanism allowing applications to
>   access the properties of an object
>   indirectly by name (or key), rather
>   than directly through invocation of an
>   accessor method or as instance
>   variables

Comment: This is it! Thanks.. this is huge and will really simplify my code.